# How would I find the transfer function of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, impedance, transfer-function

[image]

I know that I can take the inductor and resistor and find the impedance from them in parallel. But what do I do with the resistor, R3? Do I need to do a nodal analysis and solve for the Vout? Or can I say that no current flows through R3 because the circuit is open, and then use just the R1 and L || R2 values in my calculation of Vout?

Comment: Considering open output circuit, therefore eliminating R3, completely depends on the use case of this circuit and the goal of your analysis. If there will be a load connected to \$v_o(t)\$ (as most practical circuits would), then you should consider a load model. Consider approachinng this problem as "find a Thevenin equivalent" instead, it will become clearer how to analyse it.

Comment: You must define specs for Z source and load assumptions then use impedance divider formulae in s domain

Comment: The first question is : transfer into what? Once you know what the load is, model it as an impedance connected to VO. Then you have a question you can answer.

Comment: That’s what “he” said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redraw your circuit with a load impedance \$Z_{load}\$. If the output circuit is truly open, then \$Z_{load}\to\infty\$ and the following results will still be valid.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSJBiK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Node equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{v_x-v_i}{R_1} + \frac{v_x}{j\omega L} + \frac{v_x}{R_2} + \frac{v_x-v_o}{R_3}=0 \\
\frac{v_o-v_x}{R_3} + \frac{v_o}{Z_{load}} = 0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
v_i = \left(1 + \frac{R_1}{j\omega L} + \frac{R_1}{R_2} + \frac{R_1}{R_3}\right){v_x}-\frac{R_1}{R_3}v_o \\
v_x = \left(1+\frac{R_3}{Z_{load}}\right)v_o
\end{cases}
$$

$$
v_i = \left(\left(1 + \frac{R_1}{j\omega L} + \frac{R_1}{R_2} + \frac{R_1}{R_3}\right)\left(1+\frac{R_3}{Z_{load}}\right) - \frac{R_1}{R_3}\right)v_o
$$

$$
T(j\omega)=\frac{v_o}{v_i}= \frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{R_1}{j\omega L} + \frac{R_1}{R_2} + \frac{R_1}{R_3}\right)\left(1+\frac{R_3}{Z_{load}}\right) - \frac{R_1}{R_3}}
$$

Up to you to simplify further. The open circuit case makes \$R_3\$ irrelevant:

$$
T(j\omega | Z_{load}\to\infty)= \frac{1}{1 + \frac{R_1}{j\omega L} + \frac{R_1}{R_2}}
$$

Comment: And in case there is an input resistance, `Rin`, then `R1` becomes `R1+Rin`.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, the circuit is open. Those, no current flows through R3 and you can ignore it. Just use voltage divider of R1 and (R2||L)

Comment: If the output circuit is open, this circuit serves to little (or no) practical purpose. Depending on application, the question author is most likely overlooking a model for load.

Comment: This is the answer to the question as he asked it. Probably this question is from homework or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a general method of finding your transfer function. This will be the same way as [@VicenteCunha](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/98525/vicente-cunha) did it, but I will use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to do it.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5gMR9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, it is not hard to solve for \$\text{V}_2\$:

$$\text{V}_2=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag3$$

Where I used Mathematica-code to solve for that:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I5, I5 == I3 + I4, I6 == I3 + I4, I1 == I2 + I6, 
   I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, I3 == V1/R3, I4 == (V1 - V2)/R4, 
   I4 == V2/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I2 -> (R3 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I3 -> (R2 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I4 -> (R2 R3 Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I5 -> (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I6 -> (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V1 -> (R2 R3 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V2 -> (R2 R3 R5 Vi)/(
   R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5))}}
```

So, the transfer function is given by:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_4+\text{R}_5\right)}\tag4$$

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

$$\text{R}_2=\text{sL}\tag5$$

Now, for your circuit, we have that \$\text{R}_5\to\infty\$. And using that and using \$(5)\$, we can rewrite \$(4)\$ as follows:

$$\lim_{\text{R}_5\to\infty}\mathcal{h}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{v}_2\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{L}\text{R}_3\text{s}}{\text{L}\text{s}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_3}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[2]:=R2 = s*L;
FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 R3 R5)/(
  R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + R2 R3 (R4 + R5) + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  R5 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(L R3 s)/(R1 R3 + L (R1 + R3) s)
```

---

When we for example want to find the magnitude/amplitude function of your circuit when \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_3=10\space\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$\text{L}=100\space\text{mH}\$, we get:

$$\left|\lim_{\text{R}_5\to\infty}\mathcal{h}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\omega }{2 \sqrt{\omega ^2+2500000000}}\tag7$$

Where \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ (where \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency in Hertz \$\left[\text{Hz}\right]\$) and \$\text{j}^2=-1\$.

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[3]:=k = (L R3 s)/(R1 R3 + L (R1 + R3) s);
s = I*\[Omega];
R1 = 10*1000;
R3 = 10*1000;
L = 100*10^(-3);
FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[(ComplexExpand[Re[k]])^2 + (ComplexExpand[Im[k]])^2], 
 Assumptions -> \[Omega] >= 0]

Out[3]=\[Omega]/(2 Sqrt[2500000000 + \[Omega]^2])
```

Plotting that, gives:

[image]

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[4]:=Show[Plot[\[Omega]/(
  2 Sqrt[2500000000 + \[Omega]^2]), {\[Omega], 0, 2*10^5}], 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[rad/s], HoldForm[Abs[V2/Vi]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Magnitude], LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]

Out[4]=(*the output is the picture shown above*)
```